# How to make android recognise app as wallpaper app

Tags: android, wallpaper, android-wallpaper, wallpapermanager

I have created a wallpaper application and everything works fine except it won't show in the list of "apply wallpapers from" option on other apps. Is there anything to make android recognise the app as a Wallpaper app.

[image: The app should show on the list]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<intent-filter>
   <action android:name="android.intent.action.SET_WALLPAPER" />
   <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
</intent-filter>
```

Add this in your Manifest File